# Flatpickr Show 24 hour clock on mobile

Tags: flatpickr

I have a flatpickr datetime picker where I can select a date and time in 24 hour clock format. It works fine on desktop, but on mobile it puts a 12 hour AM/PM time selector in. I can disable the mobile version but it is harder to push the up and down arrows to increment the time. Is there a way to tell the mobile version to use a 12 hour time selector?

```
flatpickr('.timereported', {
enableTime: true,
dateFormat: "Y-m-d H:i",
time_24hr: true,
minuteIncrement: 1,
});
```